# Saber qual slide está passando no carousel bootstrap

Tags: javascript

Tenho um slide carousel do bootstrap, eu queria saber o momento em que um determinado slide está passando na tela usando javascript ou então parar no último slide.

Answer (score 2):

Já encontrei a solução, segue a baixo o link para o exemplo na **w3schools**
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel_event_slide&stacked=h

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

**Ficou assim:** coloquei um id em cada item e usei o 'slid.bs.carousel' que ocorre quando o carrossel corre de um item para outro.

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active" id="1">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('../img/foto1.png');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="2">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('../img/foto2.png');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="3">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('../img/foto3.png');"></div>
```

```
 <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })

    $("#myCarousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
        var i = $(".active").attr("id");
        alert(i);
        console.log(i);
    });

</script>
```